# Best fit line (least squares method) giving garbage results

Tags: least-squares, data-analysis

I don't know if I should post this in Mathematics or Stack Overflow. But its a math issue but its programming code.

Anyway, I went on this math website and put their method, it gave me total garbage results. Could be a skill issue, maybe I made a typo or didn't understand their math symbols correctly, idk.

website 1 here: https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit

Anyway, I went to a second math website, and their least squares method seemed to work...mostly. For most data clusters it works, except if the cluster is very vertical. Then it gives crap/garbage results. My guess? Is it because floating point/division by zero or something? The more vertical it is, the more the equation gives bogus results?

website 2 here:
https://www.cuemath.com/data/least-squares/

However I cannot find information on this online. I don't see anyone talking about the problem of vertical data clusters having this problem. I thought about talking to ChatGPT but they keep giving me incorrect math and programming advice so why bother.

I basically copy/pasted the math from website 1 and website 2, and I couldn't get any fitting lines from website 1. Website 2's math works 99% of the time, except when the data cluster is too vertical. The picture I uploaded shows examples, box 1 and box 2 shows the math working correctly. Box 3 is with a data cluster that's too vertical, it just gives a junk slope instead.
[picture examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGXzl.png)

Comment: The weaker the relationship, the poorer the apparent results. But it is difficult to comment without seeing an example of what you mean

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok i will upgrade the question, gimme a few mins or half an hour lol

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57685/line-of-best-fit-linear-regression-over-vertical-line#:~:text=For%20nearly%2Dvertical%20lines%2C%20the,will%20be%20large%2C%20but%20finite.) is relevant?

Comment: @lulu yeah that does seem similar to my problem

Comment: Implicit in the assumptions of linear regression is that $x$ can have any value (over some significant range), and $y$ will exhibit values that depend mostly on the corresponding value of $x$ with some random "noise" added in the vertical direction. "Vertical" sets of data don't look like this. You might look into "total least squares" regression, which minimizes the squared distance to the closest point on the line rather than to a point directly above or below.

Comment: yep i may look into that one, thanks

Comment: Please joint to your question an example of data (numerical not graphical) in a case where the difficulty occurs. Without reproducing the trouble by ourself one cannot see what exactly the problem is and one cannot help you.

Comment: I still doesn't see your numerical example joint to your question. Downvote -1.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the problem is to represent the line to fit as $y=y_0+m (x-x_0)$. To avoid the vertical problems we can fit a line in the parametric mode. $p = p_0+\lambda\vec v$. In this representation, the distance between a generic point $p_k,\ k=1,\cdots,n$ to the line is given by

$$
\delta_k^2 =\|p_k-p_0-\left((p_k-p_0)\cdot\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}\right)\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}\|^2
$$

so we need to minimize

$$
\sum_k\delta_k^2=\sum_k\|p_k-p_0-\left((p_k-p_0)\cdot\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}\right)\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}\|^2\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \|\vec v\| = 1 
$$

with the lagrangian

$$
L(p_0,\vec v,\lambda)=\sum_k\|p_k-p_0-\left((p_k-p_0)\cdot\vec v\right)\vec v\|^2+\lambda(\|\vec v\|^2 - 1) 
$$

Comment: yeah thats above my paygrade lol. maybe i should have posted in stackoverflow, what is this δ symbol?

Comment: This is definitely not a StackOverflow question.